# VBA - How to temporarily disable the Worksheet.Activate Event?

Tags: vba, excel, business-objects

I'm working on an Excel workbook that uses SAP's BusinessObjects Analysis plug-in. Whenever the workbook opens, a variable selection prompt is triggered and allows users to enter values which are then used to select data from the back-end and display it in a table format in Excel(a representation of the SAP BW Query in Excel). The problem I'm facing is the following...
Whenever the prompt selection is complete and the selection is being processed, if you spam click the worksheet tabs you fire the `Worksheet.Activate` event. The problem is that `Worksheet.Activate` handler tries to invalidate a ribbon object which itself has not been set yet. I want to prevent that and I would like the ribbon to be invalidated only if it has been set. The problem is that the ribbon must be invalidated when the worksheet is changed in order for it to load the specific buttons in the ribbon that are unique for every worksheet. Not invalidating on activating the worksheet is not an option. It would be best to eliminate the possibility of changing worksheets, before our custom ribbon has loaded.

Here's what I have tried without any success:

1. I tried disabling interactive mode with `Application.Interactive = False` as soon as the prompt appears and re-enabling it whenever the  `AOCust_OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)` ribbon `onLoad` callback has been executed and the ribbon is set.
2. I tried disabling all events using `Application.EnableEvents = False` as soon as the prompt appears and re-enabling them whenever the ribbon `onLoad` callback has been executed and the ribbon is set.
3. I tried adding the following to the `Worksheet.Activate` callback but it never exits the infinite loop which is probably expected because ribbon onLoad is not a system event and is thus never triggered.

   ```
   while ribbon is Nothing
     'waiting for ribbon onload to fire and set the value
     DoEvents
   wend
   ```

What is surprising with the second case is how the `Worksheet.Activate` event is fired when the events, to my understanding, are disabled.

Do you have any idea of how I can approach this problem so that the user cannot change the worksheet before the ribbon has been set?

Please let me know if you would like me to add code snippets to this description.

Thanks

EDIT - CODE ADDED

In Microsoft Excel Objects in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  If EnableEvents = True Then
      Debug.Print "invalidate"
      Call AOCust_Callbacks.AOCust_InvalidateRibbon
  End If
End Sub
```

In Module "Custom_Ribbon"

```
'Callback for Selections data onAction
 Sub PROMPT(control As IRibbonControl)
   EnableEvents = False
   'more prompt-related code
 End Sub
```

In Module 'AOCust_Callbacks"

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

'Callback for Ribbon OnLoad
Sub AOCust_OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  Debug.Print "setting the ribbon"
  'Start Highlighting for Workbook
  StartHighlighting
  Set AOCustRibbon = ribbon
  Debug.Print "the ribbon is now set"
  EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I spam click the worksheet tabs as soon as the prompt selection is complete and the selection is still processing, I no longer get the problem with the variable not being set when I try to invalidate the ribbon because of the if statement, but the problem is that the onload ribbon function is not executed.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you set `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Having a global variable `EnableEvents` is not the same thing.

Comment: Yes I know. I got rid of that code before I posted the snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by disabling the mouse events using `Application.interactive = False` before the selection prompt loads or the first time and re-enabling them when the ribbon has loaded. The problem was that SAP decided to use a different callback for the very first prompt called `onBeforeFirstPromptsDisplay`.As a result, my changes to the prompt callback that's in the workbook were never actually triggered because that callback is only executed when you trigger the prompt yourself through the workbook. After implementing `onBeforeFirstPromptsDisplay` everything worked. 
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution but is a work around.

You could use a global variable to handle it.

Place something like the following in a module

```
Public EventsEnabled As Boolean
Public Sub ModuleWithDisabledEvents()
    EventsEnabled = False
    Debug.Print EventsEnabled
    EventsEnabled = True
    Debug.Print EventsEnabled
End Sub
```

and then on your worksheet activation wrap your `Activate` code in an if block that looks at this variable

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Not EventsEnabled Then
        ' Do activate code here
    End If
End Sub
```

By changing the `EventsEnabled` variable you can get your code to ignore your `Activate` procedure even if events are enabled.

---

**UPDATE**:
What are you doing with the Ribbon? This is how I've implemented custom ribbons in the past and haven't experienced your issue:

In my XML File I have the following:

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Custom Tab">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Custom Group">
                    <button id="customButton" label="Custom Button" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="Callback" getVisible="GetVisible" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Then in my file I have a module named 'Ribbon' which contains:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
Dim rib As IRibbonUI

Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                         Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                         ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                         ByVal Operation As String, _
                         ByVal Filename As String, _
                         Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
                         Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
                         Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
                         ) As Long

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
#End If
Dim objRibbon As Object
CopyMemory objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer)
Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function
Public Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set rib = ribbon
    Debug.Print "ribbon:-", ObjPtr(ribbon)
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value = ObjPtr(ribbon)
End Sub
Public Sub RefreshRibbon()
    On Error GoTo RibbonError
    If rib Is Nothing Then
        Set rib = GetRibbon(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        If rib Is Nothing Then GoTo RibbonError
    Else
        rib.Invalidate
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Exit Sub
RibbonError:
    Debug.Print "There is an issue with the menu bar. Please restart the tool"
End Sub

Public Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    visible = True
End Sub
```

When the ribbon loads it sets it's memory value to `Sheet2` which it then uses to reload when it Refreshes the ribbon running `RefreshRibbon`

Comment: This is a good workaround which I thought about initially! I was hoping for a more robust implementation by setting VBA event properties but this will do the trick. If there's no other answer with a more robust solution I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: I implemented this in a way that the I set EventsEnabled to False as soon as the prompt appears and change it  to True after the ribbon is set in the ribbon onLoad. The problem now is that when I spam click, the ribbon onLoad is not executed at all.

Comment: Can you post any of your code? One of the main problems with customising the ribbon is it is very poorly documented.

Comment: please see my edited post - I added some code. I hope it helps. Thank you for responding so quickly btw.

Comment: Can you have a look at my update. I think from your code the issue is is that you're losing it's memory allocation when you invalidate it. It's difficult to debug the Ribbon as the debugger doesn't really work with it though

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. I actually haven't written this code. From what I know it was provided by SAP and was modified by some of my colleagues but investigating the issue is now assigned to me so I have to figure it out. Keep in mind that I will not be able to invalidate the ribbon until it's set because the if statement in Workbook_SheetActivate assures that the ribbon reference is set before invalidating. I think the issue is even more perverted!